# python list elements start with and end with same character

Tags: python, list

Very new and beginner to python, got a small assignment to do this

Suppose that you have a list of strings named samples. 
Write a Python loop that goes through the list and counts the number of strings where the string length is 2 or more and
the first and last characters of the strings are the same.

Test your code on the following three versions of the list samples:

```
samples = ['aba', 'xyz', 'aa', 'x', 'bbb']<br/>
samples = ['', 'x', 'xy', 'xyx', 'xx']<br/>
samples = ['aaa', 'be', 'abc', 'hello']
```

What I tried did not work it returned nothing for me:

```
samples=['aba', 'xyz','aa', 'x', 'bbb']
for elem in samples:
 if ( len(elem) >=2 and str.startswith('"') and str.endswith('"')):
  print(elem)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quotation marks are not part of the string; they will not match for you.  Rather, you want an innermost comparison such as

```
elem.endswith(elem[0])
```

Note that **str** is the documentation's way of saying "put your string here".  Let's update the program so far:

```
samples=['aba', 'xyz','aa', 'x', 'bbb']
for elem in samples:
    if (len(elem) >=2 and elem.endswith(elem[0])):
        print(elem)
```

Output:

```
aba
aa
bbb
```

Comment: thank you , i think i understand this now , your saying if the element ends with the same character that is in the 0 index correct?

Comment: Right: index 0 is the first character.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one line answer, hope it helps:

```
results = [x for x in samples if len(x)>=2 and x[0]==x[-1]]
```

Basically results is a new list created from filtering samples with 2 conditions.